# I was wondering how to pass the double value as arrays and receive them on the other side this is what I have for code:

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass a double value that are arrays in a  tag. How do I receive the and split the arrays apart on the other side? This is the code that I have:

```
<?php
 print("<select name='dsc[]' multiple='multiple' id='searchable-select' multiple>");
//Create new SQL object  
$db = new NSC_SQL($db2config);
$db->from($qadbifld, "dbifld, substr(dbitxt,1,25) as FLDTEXT");
$db->where("upper(dbiatr)='PF' and (DBILIB='".$nscmod72d."' or DBILIB='".$aedata72."')    ");
$db->group("dbitxt,dbifld");
$db->order("dbitxt,dbifld");
$db->select();
$results = $db->fetchAssoc();
foreach($results as $row)
{
    $fieldName = trim($row['DBIFLD']);
    $fieldDesc = trim($row['FLDTEXT']);
    print("<option VALUE='$fieldDesc,$fieldName'>$fieldDesc  -  $fieldName  </option>");
}
print("</select>");
?>
```

This is how I'm trying to receive it on the other side:

```
<?PHP
 $dsc = $_POST['dsc'];
 list($fieldDesc, $fieldName) = explode(":", $dsc);
//Put the elements of the array in hidden fields here!
print_r($fieldDesc);
print_r($fieldName);
foreach ($fieldDesc as $key => $value1)
{
    echo "<input type=hidden name='dsc[]' value='$value1'>";
}
?>
```

This is wrote in PHP

It has to be this way so that only one option is passed to the multi-select box.
Thanks for any help you guys may have for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple select element

Consider the code below

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $dsc = $_POST['dsc'];

    foreach ($dsc as $val){

        $data = explode(",", $val);
        $fieldDesc = $data[0]; 
        $fieldName = $data[1];

        echo "<input type=hidden name='dsc[]' value='$fieldDesc'>";
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<select name='dsc[]' multiple='multiple' id='searchable-select' multiple size="7">
    <option value="a,1">a,1</option>
    <option value="b,2">b,2</option>
    <option value="c,3">c,3</option>
    <option value="d,4">d,4</option>
    <option value="e,5">e,5</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

If you dont get let me know

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be joining the values together with `,`, then splitting them with `:`. You kind of have to use the same separator for joining and splitting.

Comment: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Comment: I keep getting these two warnings.  Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in///Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in! I did notice that and changed it right after I posted. Made the change and still the same problem.

Comment: I'm confused by how your scripts work together, but if you name an input `dsc[]` then `$_POST['dsc']` will be an array, and you can't `explode` an array.

Comment: dsc[] works with a multi-select box to pull multiple values from a database and display them in a table.

Comment: I figured out to make it work. I break it down with a nested foreach statement